# How to get text from ListView item?

Tags: java, android

I have a listView that contains person name and phonenumber. The idea of this is to call to that person whose name is clicked, but I cant figure out how can I get person number out from the ListView.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaikki_numerot);

    // create a cursor to query the Contacts on the device to start populating a listview
    cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);

    String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}; // get the list items for the listadapter could be TITLE or URI


    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}; // sets the items from above string to listview

    // new listadapter, created to use android checked template
    SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);


    setListAdapter(listadapter);


    lv = getListView();
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            //here is the onClick where you should be able to make call

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your onclick add to[position] and check its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            //here is the onClick where you should be able to make call
            String person_number = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
             {
                 String data=(String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                 //Let data= "item1 item2 item3" for example:
                  String[] parts = data.split(" ");
                  String part1 = parts[0]; // item1
                  String part2 = parts[1]; // item2

             }});
```

`data` contains your clicked position's data. Do what ever you want to do with t

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position` object you getting in your `setOnItemClickListener`. Use this `position` to get the data from your `cursor1`.